# Dificuldade em fazer verificação de dados no php com o mysql

Tags: php, html, jquery, mysql, ajax

Estou tentando fazer uma verificação no banco para saber se já tem um usuário com cadastrado com o email digitado pelo hmtl, fiz esse script php, porém a execução sempre para no primeiro if mesmo que o email digitado não esteja no banco ainda.

Acredito que a lógica que utilizei esta correta, não consigo identificar onde estou errando

```
<?php
include_once("conexao_class.php");
include_once("usuario_class.php");


$My = new MySQLiConnection();


$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$sobrenome = $_POST['sobrenome'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$sexo = $_POST['sexo'];
$telefone_fixo = $_POST['telefone'];
$telefone_movel = $_POST['celular'];
$senha = $_POST['senha'];

$obj_usu = new usuario($nome,$sobrenome,$telefone_fixo,$telefone_movel,$email,$sexo,$senha);



$My = new MySQLiConnection();// conecta-se automaticamente ao servidor MySQL
  $verifica = "SELECT * FROM tb_usuario WHERE nm_email = '$email'";

// a conexão é fechada automaticamente no fim do script.
      // retornando a falta de paramentro ao ajax      

      $result = $My->query($verifica) or die(mysql_error());



        if (mysqli_num_rows($result)<=0)
      {
            if(isset($_POST['terms']))
                {

                $result2 = $obj_usu->AddUsuario();
                echo"$result2";
                }
                else{
                // retornando ao ajax dados inválidos
                      echo"3";
                    }
      }


    else{
    // retornando ao ajax email já cadastrado
         echo"1";
         }
?>
```

Comment: A lógica está correta, quem sabe o erro está em outra parte do código não postado. Provavelmente no input email

Comment: eu verifiquei input e está correto, teste também retornar o a variável email para ver se a mesma estava preenchida e realmente retornou o email, não faço ideia de onde está o erro

Comment: Você não consegue  é retornar  `echo"3";`

Comment: Quando uma resposta resolver seu problema, não responda no campo destinado a respostas e nem precisa agradecer em comentários, apenas marque a resposta como aceita. Veja como em https://i.stack.imgur.com/evLUR.png e porque em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Answer (score 0):

Essa condição `if(isset($_POST['terms'])` sempre retorna verdadeira ao submeter o formulário mesmo que o input não tenha sido preenchido

> Alem de testar se os posts foram iniciados verifique se não estão vazios

```
 // verifique se foi iniciado e não está vazio
 if (isset($_POST["email"]) && !empty($_POST["email"])) {

 ...............
 ..............

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result)<=0){

        // verifique se foi iniciado e não está vazio
        if (isset($_POST["terms"]) && !empty($_POST["terms"]))
        {

            echo "2";
        }
        else{
            // retornando ao ajax dados inválidos
                  echo"3";
        }
    }
    else{
     // retornando ao ajax email já cadastrado
     echo"1";
    }

 .....................
 .....................
```

Comment: Amigo, fiz a alteração que vc passou e não funcionou, acontece que eu utilizava esse código e funcionava perfeitamente, hoje fui fazer algumas alteração pois estou usando POO agora e deu esse problema, o script é praticamente o mesmo

Comment: @Reignomo veja se assim que deve funcionar nesse exemplo http://kithomepage.com/sos/verificacao-dados.php

Comment: @Reignomo, com o código que você postou só dá para enxergar de errado o que eu disse na resposta. No mais, só Deus ou um adivinho para imaginar o resto do seu código para poder analisar.